# I want to split a long period of time by one day in python, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.x

The IDE didn't report any error, however it takes a longtime to run the program,so what's the matter

```
import datetime


def time_split(start_time,end_time):
    t = 1
    new_time = []
    while (t > 0):
        new_time_point = end_time + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
        new_time.append(new_time_point)
        t = new_time_point.day - start_time.day
    print new_time

s_t = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=-5)
e_t = datetime.datetime.now()

time_split(s_t,e_t)
```

Answer (score 2):

`end_time` is now and `start_time` is 5 days before now.

Therefore `new_time_point = end_time + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)` is always one day before now and `t = new_time_point.day - start_time.day` is always 4 and `while (t > 0):` is an infinite loop.

Instead of

```
new_time_point = end_time + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
```

you probably meant to subtract one day from the *previous* `new_time_point` instead of from `end_time`, so that `t` can become 0 eventually. You then need to initialize `new_time_point` with `end_time` before the loop starts:

```
import datetime


def time_split(start_time, end_time):
    t = 1
    new_time = []
    new_time_point = end_time
    while t > 0:
        new_time_point = new_time_point + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
        new_time.append(new_time_point)
        t = new_time_point.day - start_time.day
    print(new_time)

s_t = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-5)
e_t = datetime.datetime.now()

time_split(s_t, e_t)
```